# how to pass name attribute in Beginform helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view-helpers

Here, I want to pass name attributes to the Form. But this is passing name as query string: Following is the code I have used:

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "AjaxUpload", new { @name = "form1" }))
    {

I have also remove @ at name it works as query string. WOuld you please tell how to pass name attributes like below:

```
<form name = "form1" action = "..">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a wrong overload of [`BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx) and it treats the `new { @name = "form1" }` as the route values collection.

You need to use a different overload which allows you to pass html attributes [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714.aspx):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
              "Upload", //action name
              "AjaxUpload", // controller name
              FormMethod.Post, // form method
              new { name = "form1" }) // htmlAttributes
       ){

}
```